# Angular 2 - How can I block GUI rendering while waiting on http request to finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular, typescript

It's possible to wait rendering the GUI/components and show it when the task has finished.

Like

1. Request the website in browser.
2. Start a task loading some data from server.
3. When task has finish tell angular2 to continue loading in all components.
4. Rendering finish.

---

```
</head>
<body>
  <div *ngIf="UserData">
    <app>Laddar...</app>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!UserData">
    Laddar...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So blocking `<app>` top component, all components in the module will be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="data">
  {{content}}
</div>
```

```
http.get(...).subscribe(val => this.data = val);
```